# Changing src attribute for an audio element doesn't work

Tags: audio, reactjs

Changing src attribute for an audio element doesn't work:

```
var Audio = React.createClass({
    render : function() {
        return (
            <audio src={this.props.data.songUrl}/>
        );
    }   
});

var Music = React.createClass({
    render : function() {
        return (
            <article className="music">
                <article className="musicContent">
                    <MusicButton data={Data} />
                    <List />
                    <Footer />
                </article>
            </article>
        );
    }
});

var MusicButton = React.createClass({
    getInitialState : function() {
        return {
            isPlay : true,
            count : 0
        }
    },
    musicPlay : function () {
        var audio = React.findDOMNode(this.refs.audio);
        if(this.state.isPlay) {
            audio.play();
            this.setState({isPlay: false});
        } else {
            audio.pause();
            this.setState({isPlay: true});
        }
    },
    getBackWardMusic : function() {
        this.setState({count: ++this.state.count});
        var audio = React.findDOMNode(this.refs.audio);
        audio.play();
    },
    getForwardMusic : function() {
        this.setState({count: --this.state.count});
        var audio = React.findDOMNode(this.refs.audio);
        audio.play();
    },

    render : function() {
        var classString = 'iconMusic icon-pause';
        if(this.state.isPlay) {
            classString = 'iconMusic icon-pause';
        } else {
            classString += ' rotate';
        }

        return (
            <header className="musicHeader">
                <Audio ref="audio" data={this.props.data[this.state.count]} />
                <span onClick={this.getBackWardMusic} className="iconMusic icon-backward"></span>
                <span onClick={this.musicPlay} className={classString}></span>
                <span onClick={this.getForwardMusic} className="iconMusic icon-forward"></span>
            </header>
        );
    }
});
```

Comment: Can you explain what you're trying to do? What is it that isn't working?

Comment: Please read about [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I'm trying to do music player.I want to click button to change src of audio,but,the music player does not play.The problem is that I paid xxx.mp3 audio of src, but the audio does not play.

Answer (score 2):

after changing the source of audio you need to .load() first, before play() plays the new source.
you may like to use .oncanplaythroug = .play()

Comment: Ohh thanks for the load() tip! Changing the src wasn't enough to make it play!

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a specific answer for your question but I've found that media elements have their own lifecycle that I'm not sure is handled correctly in the React wrappers. The React and media element lifecycles have subtle interactions that are difficult to get right.

E.g., in Chrome, media elements don't release their resources unless you set `src=''` and if you do this in a React class, followed by a `src='something-else'` then I suspect the `src=''` can get optimised away.

To manage a `video` element, for example, I wrapped it in a React component and attached my own event listeners to the `video` DOM element to help manage its state and also managed cases like `src=''` and others by directly manipulating the DOM element in  `componentWillReceiveProps` and `componentWillUpdate` based on what was changing.

Sorry I've not given a complete answer. It would take a lot of time to completely describe everything but I hope this helps a bit.

Comment: Thx, @edoloughlin.I have solved this question.I used setTimeout(function() {audio.load(); audio.play();}, 0) to solve this problem.Your answer has given me help.thx!!!

Comment: Hey @useLessliang, I saw you solved it by using setTimeout, but did you try Freek van der want, solution below? It worked like a charm for me, without the need of setTimeout!